# bag_mars function in tidymodels package

Tags: r, tidymodels

While using the bag_mars function in the parsnip package, I encountered the following problem:

```
bag_mars_model <- 
  bag_mars( num_terms = tune(),
            prod_degree = tune(),
            prune_method = tune(),
  ) %>% 
  set_engine("earth") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
```

error:

> parsnip could not locate an implementation for `bag_mars`  model specifications using the `earth` engine.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: This is correct. We have a change in the new parsnip version that will give a more informative message about what extension package is required. @MrFlick can you add this as an answer so that it will show up as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the `baguette` package to use that engine. Try running

```
install.packages("baguette")
```

See https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/details_bag_mars_earth.html